# What should I say when speak about timetable?

Tags: difference

> I read a book from 2:00 p.m. to 3:00 p.m

( I want to say that I read a book, but in a week I am going to read other book, because I will finish with first one and it is my timetable that I have been doing the same things at the same time all my life)

Or

> I read books from 2:00 p.m. to 3:00 p.m.

> I watch a film from 4:00 p.m. to 6:00 p.m.

Or

> I watch films from 4:00 p.m. to 6:00 p.m

Comment: Either is possible. The singular is taken distributively, and doesn't imply that it is the same book, or the same film, every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very subtle difference in intent.

"I read a book from 2:00 p.m. to 3:00 p.m" has the connotation that you are settling down, curling up in a chair and getting comfy so as to immerse yourself into an hour of escape into a story.

"I read books from 2:00 p.m. to 3:00 p.m." does not have that feeling: it's more that it's your time to study various books and it doesn't really matter which books, it's just that at this time that's what you have timetabled.

Comment: I have marked your answer down as I believe it is misleading. **Reading a book from 2 p,m. to 3 p.m. implies something regular - each day, each Sunday, when it's raining etc. It does not imply that you are comfortable or wish to lose yourself in a story. The statement with **books** in the plural carries the same implication, but simply refers to more than one book. I shall happily delete my comment if you reconsider your answer.

Comment: @RonaldSole No don't worry, your reality is different from my reality and if you consider my reality to be spurious then it's not up to me to impose my will upon it.

Comment: ** We use the simple present tense when an action is happening right now, or when it happens regularly ....**        https://www.grammarly.com/blog/simple-present/

Comment: @RonaldSole How is that directly relevant to my answer? I don't understand what your comment adds.